# Post WWI - Peace Conference flow of capital

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-history

I'm researching a bit into how countries went about servicing their debt obligations, which were quite high after the major spending during wartime. Liaquat Ahamed notes:

> As the Peace Conference was winding to its end, Maynard Keynes,
> distressed at how the negotiations were going, decided on his own
> initiative to put together a comprehensive plan for the financial
> reconstruction of Europe. Reparations should be fixed at $5 billion,
> to be paid by Germany in the form of long-term bonds issued to the
> Allies, which they would in turn assign to pay their war debts to the
> US government. All other obligations were to be forgiven. It was a
> clever scheme. The US government would be functionally lending Germany
> money, which in turn would go to pay reparations to the Allies, who in
> turn would use those proceeds to settle their loans. The money would
> start in a United States flush with gold, and eventually return there
> full circle.

It seems that the US delegates ultimately rejected this proposal but the mechanics of the above plan interest me. But I'm having trouble making sense of it, perhaps a worked out example would help, to see how exactly the capital goes "full circle." I just want to see how it would work at the institution and debt instrument level,

1. Germany issues treasuries, suppose a 30 year
2. Suppose a commercial bank in England buys this 30 year German
   treasury
3. (Where it gets confusing to me) England puts the treasury on the
   secondary market and US buys it?
4. Assuming Germany stays within its covenants for this 30 year, then
   it will have paid the principal and interest to the US. But not sure
   how that makes England's war debts any better off.

### Question

Could someone correct my numbered steps above so that we may see a (contrived but plausible) worked out example of how governments and buyside institutions would have carried out Keyne's plan, resulting in capital coming "full circle" back to the US?

### Question